# Handling Much of Google Maps 3 Marker

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had lot of marker on my Google Maps v.3. My maps is running so slow because there is too much marker on that
So, what about indexing the database to increase the marker's load? Will that have any effect? If no, do you have any ideas? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the bottleneck is.

If the bottleneck is at database seek, adding indexes to your database would definitely help. You might want to refer to the [MySQL indexing documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) for some guide.

Otherwise, if the bottleneck is at the front-end, ie. too heavy on the JavaScript from having to load too many markers at once, here are some tips:

- Try not to have too many markers displayed at once.
- If the markers are related to time, you may want to remove some old markers off your maps to free up some memory.
- If there are a lot of markers to be displayed all at once, you may wish to use timer (`setTimeout`) to stagger the display, for example, show a marker at every 100ms instead of all at once.
- If possible, redesign your UI to allow showing only say 20 most relevant markers at a time while hinting to your users to load another 20 if needed.